Recovering data from a partition whose partition table is overwritten?
Due to a mistake I made with Testdisk, the partition table of the SSD on which a Kubuntu and the home directory partition are/were located has been overwritten.
Also a Windows 10 on the same drive is not displayed and cannot be launched.
The blue PC Rescue Screen appears. But I can boot Debian from an extra HDD.
In Debian in the KDE Partition Manager I see that only the /boot /efi SYSTEM and the RECOVERY Partition (at the end) are displayed on the SSD, in between is a large unallocated ‘partition’. There were Windows 10 and three ext4 before using Testdisk.
Is it possible to recover data from an ext4 partition whose partition table is overwritten?
more info additionally:
It started with shrinking the partition with Kubuntu via KDE Partition Manger.
Maybe this post helps for  understanding, the comments also
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529895/system-doesnt-start-due-to-bad-superblock
I overwrote the partitions with TesDisk even though it displayed: The partition couldn't be repaired.
But in kind of hope and desperation I wrote all what TesDisk had done.
I couldn't use the disk anymore since Kubuntu could not be booted.
And I didn't write data to a new partition, not possible.
But I have tried to access the disk later after I booted from a Debian System on a separate HDD.
After first boot the file manger has shown the SSD but it couldn’t be mounted.
After second boot (or later can’t say) the disk was not shown anymore in the file manager, only displayed in KDE  Partition Manager.
But only as described above, with one large unallocated ‘partition’ between SYSTEM and RECOVERY partition.

You overwrote the partitions then used the disk or immediately stopped using it? Ironically TestDisk is the tool to recover your data.

So were your partitions deleted then data written to the new partitions or did you only delete the partitions? Please [edit] your question to include enough information to answer your question

@Ramhound, I hope you find answer to your questions above. I did not delete partitions  but have overwritten the partition's table.
Thanks for your time.

Annotation to the other question in askubuntu: I have written there Xubuntu but I had meant Kubuntu (it happened by speech to text on the phone). Its the same system respectively its home partition.
